# Grails UI in 2.3.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am coming from the `Spring + Hibernate + JSF/primefaces` site. What I like in Grails is its scaffolding site, so that basic CRUD apps can be created rather quickly.

However, which libaries do you recommend for a beginner in Grails for creating a UI? It should be created quickly and straightforward and also be feature rich (have a look at the [primefaces libary](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very basic `GSP` pages are really powerful, especially when combined with any modern JS library. With them you can assemble a complex rich GUIs in instant (well, almost :) )

There are also numerous grails plugins to include almost any view technology of your choice into your web-app, e.g. http://grails.org/plugin/kickstart-with-bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap once installed you can use the documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/ as your guide.